# Solving solvable septics using only cubics?

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, galois-theory

After the satisfying resolution of my [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/437322/) on the Kondo-Brumer quintic, I decided to revisit my [old post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/155087/) on septic equations.

**I. Solution by eta quotients**

The septic mentioned in that post may not look much,

$$h^2 -7^3h\,(x+5x^2+7x^3)\\ -7^4\,(x + 7 x^2 + 21 x^3 + 49 x^4 + 147 x^5 + 343 x^6 + 343 x^7) =0 $$

but has some surprises. It is solvable in radicals for any $h$, but also by eta quotients,

$$h = \left(\frac{\sqrt7\,\eta(7\tau)}{\;\eta(\tau)}\right)^4,\quad x=\left(\frac{\eta(49\tau)}{\eta(\tau)}\right)$$

**II. Solution by radicals**

If we do a change of variables $x = (y-1)/7$ and $h = -n-8$, we get a much simpler form,

$$y^7 + 14y^4 - 7n y^3 - 14(3 + n)y^2 - 28y - (n^2 - 5n + 9) = 0$$

Surprisingly, its solution needs only a *cubic* Lagrange resolvent,

$$y = u_1^{1/7} +  u_2^{1/7} +  u_3^{1/7}$$

so the $u_i$ are the three *real* roots of,

$$u^3 - (n^2 + 2n + 9)u^2 + (n^3 + 5n^2 + 14n + 15)u + 1 = 0$$

which has negative discriminant $d = -(n^2 + 3n + 9)^2 (n^3 + 2n^2 - 8)^2$ so always has three real roots.

**III. Tschirnhausen transformation**

While browsing the book ["Generic Polynomials"](http://library.msri.org/books/Book45/files/book45.pdf) (*thanks, Rouse!*), in page 30 I saw the generic cubic for $C_3 = A_3$,

$$v^3 + n v^2 - (n + 3)v + 1 = 0$$

Suspecting it was connected to the cubic I found, I verified they were indeed related by a quadratic Tshirnhausen transformation,

$$u = 2 v^2 + (n + 2) v - 1$$

Note that the discriminant of the septic (in $y$), resolvent cubic, and generic cubic have the common square factor $(n^2+3n+9)^2$.

**IV. Questions**

1. In general, a solvable septic has a sextic Langrange resolvent. So what are the Galois conditions such that this is reduced to a a cubic resolvent?
2. Would any parametric septic solvable just by a cubic resolvent share a common square factor with the generic polynomial for $C_3 = A_3$? Or is the one involved in $\frac{\eta(\tau)}{\eta(7\tau)}$ a "special" case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding question 1), of course the obvious (sufficient) answer is "When the Galois group is contained in $C_7\rtimes C_3$". That's not quite the case here, but "almost". To be precise, your septic has discriminant $-7\cdot f(h)^2$ (for a suitable polynomial $f(h)$, so the quadratic subextension of the splitting field over $\mathbb{Q}(h)$ is $\mathbb{Q}(h)(\sqrt{-7})\subset\mathbb{Q}(h)(\zeta_7)$. Making the expression $y=u_1^{1/7}+u_2^{1/7}+u_3^{1/7}$ well-defined requires picking the *correct* 7-th roots inside the splitting fields $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[7]{u_i}, \zeta_7)$, so I guess this is where the above quadratic subextension gets eaten up.

Comment: Thanks. I've made an edit to the post. The resolvent cubic has negative square discriminant $d$ so always has three _real_ roots $u_i$. The expression $y = u_1^{1/7} + u_2^{1/7} + u_3^{1/7}$ then gives the unique real root of the septic. (Of course, for the septic's complex six roots, one has to affix the proper powers of $\zeta_7$.)

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII Sure, I didn't mean to say that the post lacked information, just that at this point, algebraically speaking, the $\sqrt{-7}$ secretely sneaks in when one wants to switch between the different roots (much like in a polynomial of the form $x^7-a$, where I guess you'd say this doesn't need any resolvent at all, even though it still has full solvable Galois group $C_7\rtimes C_6$)

Comment: I finally managed to properly define $y = \zeta^k r_1 + \zeta^{4k}r_2 + \zeta^{2k}r_3$ to recover the septic. Kindly see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out part of my second question, on whether this septic was a special case. The answer, perhaps not surprisingly, depends on Ramanujan's work. Given the [*Ramanujan theta function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_theta_function),

$$f(a,b) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a^{n(n+1)/2} \; b^{n(n-1)/2}$$

Define the following theta quotients,

\begin{align}
r_1 &= \frac{1}{q^{2/7}}\frac{f(-q^2,-q^5)}{f(-q,-q^6)} = \frac{1}{q^{2/7}}\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(1-q^{7n-2})(1-q^{7n-5})}{(1-q^{7n-1})(1-q^{7n-6})}\\
r_2 &= \frac{-1\;}{q^{1/7}}\frac{f(-q^3,-q^4)}{f(-q^2,-q^5)} \;=\; \frac{-1\;}{q^{1/7}}\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(1-q^{7n-3})(1-q^{7n-4})}{(1-q^{7n-2})(1-q^{7n-5})}\\
r_3 &= \frac{1}{q^{-3/7}}\frac{f(-q,-q^6)}{f(-q^3,-q^7)} = \frac{1}{q^{-3/7}}\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(1-q^{7n-1})(1-q^{7n-6})}{(1-q^{7n-3})(1-q^{7n-4})}
\end{align}

Then the cubic formed by their $7$th powers

$$P(u) = (u-r_1^7)(u-r_2^7)(u-r_3^7) = 0$$

has coefficients in the *Dedekind eta quotient* $ m = \left(\frac{\eta(\tau)}{\eta(7\tau)}\right)^4,$

$$P(u) = u^3- (57 + 14 m + m^2) u^2-(289 + 126 m + 19 m^2 + m^3) u +1 =0$$

(This cubic in fact was also found by Ramanujan.) While the septic formed by the expression,

$$P(y)=\prod_{k=0}^6 \Big(y - (\zeta^k r_1 + \zeta^{4k}r_2 + \zeta^{2k}r_3)\Big) = 0$$

with $\zeta = e^{2\pi i/7}$ also has coefficients in $m$,

$$P(y) = y^7 + 14y^4 + 7 (8 + m) y^3 + 14 (5 + m) y^2 - 28y - (113 + 21 m + m^2) = 0$$

Of course, a root of $P(y)$ is then,

$$y = r_1 + r_2 + r_3 = u_1^{1/7} + u_2^{1/7} + u_3^{1/7}$$

and a minor change of variable $m \to -(n+8)$ will recover the cubic and septic in my question.

**P.S.** While I now know how to construct the septic from first principles, I do not fully understand why its solvability "carries over" to any $m$ (not just the original eta quotient), nor why $P(y)$ now relates eta quotients *in two ways*,

$$\text{If}\; m = \left(\frac{\eta(\tau)}{\eta(7\tau)}\right)^4,\; \text{then}\; y = \left(\frac{\eta(\tau/7)}{\eta(7\tau)}\right)+1$$

$$\text{If}\; m = \left(\frac{\sqrt7\,\eta(7\tau)}{\;\eta(\tau)}\right)^4,\; \text{then}\; y = \left(\frac{7\eta(49\tau)}{\eta(\tau)}\right)+1$$

I just figure Nature is very economical with her polynomials.

Answer (score 0):

Did you notice that the polynomial is essentially the same as the (unique) [eta product identity for prime squared level](https://web.archive.org/web/20190709153537/http://eta.math.georgetown.edu/etaL/index.html) [for $p=7$](https://web.archive.org/web/20180903181810/http://eta.math.georgetown.edu/etaL/level49.gp)? So there should be a connection, and equivalent ones for each prime (square).

Comment: Yes, accidentally. I was going over solvable septics in [Kluener's database](http://galoisdb.math.upb.de/) of reduced form $x^7+ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$ when I realized the connection. But thanks to digging deeper, do you know this has a **partner** parametric septic that differs only in the last 2 coefficients? I post about it soon.

Comment: The pair to that septic (and other solvable $p=6m+1$) is in this [new post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/438594/). It doesn't seem to relate eta quotients, just a consequence of the method I used that generates them in pairs.